# Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to store a time from my textbox field value but I got this exception error, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!:

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime.
```

**Passing textbox value:**

```
.CamActiveDateFrom = CDate(uitxtCamDateStart.Text.Trim)
```

**My variable and property:**

```
Private _camActiveTimeFrom As Nullable(Of TimeSpan)

Public Property CamActiveTimeFrom() As Nullable(Of TimeSpan)

Get     

Return Me._camActiveTimeFrom        

End Get     

Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of TimeSpan))            

Me._camActiveTimeFrom = value      

End Set    

End Property
```

**Parameter:**

```
 AddInParameter(dbCommand,

    "@ActiveTimeFrom", DbType.Time, 6, DBNull.Value)                

    If (.CamActiveTimeFrom).HasValue Then

     dbCommand.Parameters("@ActiveTimeFrom").Value = .CamActiveTimeFrom     

End If
```

Comment: Which line throws the error, exactly?

Comment: Hi, when I execute my my SQL command: retAutoID = CType(ExecuteScalar(dbCommand), Integer)

Comment: The error message says it all. A TimeSpan is not a DateTime. The two types are not compatible.

Answer (score 7):

`DbType.Time` is documented as:

> A type representing a SQL Server DateTime value. If you want to use a SQL Server time value, use `SqlDbType.Time`.

So *either* use `SqlDbType.Time` instead, *or* set the value to a `DateTime` value instead of a `TimeSpan` value.

Admittedly [this mapping table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) show the `DbType.Time` mapping to `TimeSpan`, so there's some inconsistency here - but if you can use a more specific type, that can only be good.

Of course it's easy to construct a `DateTime` from a `TimeSpan` if you want to - you should probably decide on a specific date to always use (e.g. 1st January 2000) so that you can then compare values within the database and *effectively* get a comparison of just the time bits.

Comment: Just found this years later, but when I try 

db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "TimeOfDayStart", SqlDbType.Time, newFolderSelectionValue.TimeOfDayStart);

I get 

Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to 'System.Data.DbType'

If I try to cast it

db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "TimeOfDayStart", (DbType)SqlDbType.Time, newFolderSelectionValue.TimeOfDayStart);

I get

System.ArgumentException : No mapping exists from DbType 32 to a known SqlDbType.

Comment: Figured it out will add another comment instead of replying to yours.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use AddInParameter with a column of data type time, you need to use the SqlDbType instead of DbType (as described in Jon Skeet's answer)

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ActiveTimeFrom", SqlDbType.Time, 6, DBNull.Value)
```

instead of

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ActiveTimeFrom", DbType.Time, 6, DBNull.Value)
```

BUT.

In order you use SqlDbType.Time instead of DbType.Time, you must declare your Database object as an SqlDatabase, that is

```
SqlDatabase db = (SqlDatabase)DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

instead of

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

as otherwise it won't take the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I hav the same problem. And I soloved it just used "ToString()".

my code as following:
the date type of "info.START_TIME" is TimeSpan.

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@START_TIME", DbType.Time, info.START_TIME.ToString());
```